Travelling as a dual national (UK and Denmark) from Denmark to Australia - which passport should I use?
I have recently become a dual national (British by birth; Danish by naturalisation), and am about to travel from Denmark to Australia with a day in Singapore.  I have had a valid UK passport for many years and have recently obtained a Danish passport.
In order to leave the Schengen area I will need my Danish passport, so I will definitely take that with me. It will also be simpler to use the same (Danish) passport as the "primary" passport for flights and immigration in Singapore and Australia (including applying for visas etc), so I plan to do that. But is there any benefit to also taking my UK passport with me - either in general, or specifically for commonwealth countries? As far as I can see there is no difference in visa requirements/processing for UK and Danish nationals in either Singapore or Australia, but maybe there is something I am missing? I am also not sure if I should declare to border agents in Singapore and/or Australia that I am a dual national?
I know that when I enter the UK I should use my UK passport and when I enter/leave a Schengen country I must use my Danish passport. But as this trip does not involve the UK, does that mean I can (or even should?) leave my UK passport at home? I guess it is always possible that I will end up needing UK consular assistance while abroad, or that a flight cancellation/modification will end up with me transiting through Heathrow, but both of those seem unlikely. I have tried searching for a definitive answer but haven't found one, so I would greatly appreciate personal experiences from other dual nationals!

Being re-routed through the UK is not as unlikely as you indicate and having your passport will make that easier.

There's always a chance that some unforseen emergency could arise for which you would need your UK passport.

You can travel freely in the UK on the Danish passport, you can even use the electronic gates.

@JackAidley Only until 2 April 2025

@Crazydre seems unlikely that "about to travel" means after April next year, no? :)

@JackAidley It's in November, just saying in general

Starting on 2 April 2025, Danish nationals not covered by the EU rules in the UK will require an electronic travel authorization (ETA) to transit the UK, so if travelling on or after that date, bring your UK passport just in case of any disruption involving re-routing through the UK.
Other than that, use your Danish passport for all purposes, including for eVisitor registration (assuming you're visiting for tourism/business for up to 3 months)

Thanks - the trip is November 2024 so no concerns about ETA for UK transit, but I guess it wouldn't hurt to have my UK passport as a backup.

@MattDenwood I see no use in doing it, but of course 100% up to you

Yes, I just found it and suggested an edit. Please avoid using unexplained acronyms where possible as they are often confusing. I had no idea what that was despite living in the UK as a dual US/Greek national.

@terdon You'll not need an ETA just FYI as long as you live in the UK, especially if you have settled status (which you do if you moved there before 2021), which you don't lose even if you move away, as long as you visit at least once every 5 years

Yes, I know. I was just saying that I am someone who does have a passing interest in the UK travel regulations, so you'd think I might have heard of the term "ETA", but I hadn't, so I think it is safe that many others wouldn't have either, so explaining what ETA means would be helpful.

I am a Dual UK and Irish citizen so I am sometimes faced with a similar choice.  For example, I just flew Birmingham to Bangkok via Munich.  I expected that I would not go through immigration in Munich so the advantage of bringing my Irish passport was low.  So low, that the risk was losing it outweighed the small potential value.
That is your choice: a small potential convenience versus a small risk.
I have a third choice which you don't have: I have an Irish passport card.  This is the size of a credit card and hence very easy to carry.  So, if I had to go out at Munich I could use it.  It is only valid in the EU, EEA, CH, and a few other places but elsewhere the value of UK, Irish, and Danish is very similar.
